# How to execute one particular workflow action in Oozie. If I killed Oozie workflow manually?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow, apache-crunch

I have below Oozie workflow,Suppose manually I killed the job when action "Do_task1" was executing, but still I want to execute action "Do_task2" in spite of killing oozie job manually(when action "Do_task1" was running). How can I do that?

```
<workflow-app name="simple-Workflow"
    xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.4">
    <start to = "Do_task1" />
    <!—Step 1 -->
    <action name = "Do_task1">
        <hive xmlns = "uri:oozie:hive-action:0.4">
            <job-tracker>xyz.com:8088</job-tracker>
            <name-node>hdfs://rootname</name-node>
            <script>hdfs_path_of_script/external.hive</script>
        </hive>
        <ok to = "Do_task2" />
        <error to = "kill_job" />
    </action>
    <!—Step 2 -->
    <action name = "Do_task2">
        <hive xmlns = "uri:oozie:hive-action:0.4">
            <job-tracker>xyz.com:8088</job-tracker>
            <name-node>hdfs://rootname</name-node>
            <script>hdfs_path_of_script/orc.hive</script>
        </hive>
        <ok to = "end" />
        <error to = "kill_job" />
    </action>
    <kill name = "kill_job">
        <message>Job failed</message>
    </kill>
    <end name = "end" />
</workflow-app>
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the oozie workflow is killed by killing the first action, it can not be restarted unless this property is set to true in the properties file.

```
oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true
```

If you have configured this property , after executing the command:

oozie job -rerun jobId

It will restart the workflow from  "Do_task1" and not  "Do_task2" with old properties.

Or another way to execute only the second action is : set

```
 <start to = "Do_task2"/>
```

and run the workflow again.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger that specific oozie action.

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:8080/oozie -rerun <FailedOrKilledWorkflowId> -action <actionName or actionId>
```